# Como que eu posso medir o tempo de execução de um programa em c++?

Tags: c++

Fiz um programa que gera um vetor aleatoriamente e depois o ordena, usando bubble sort, agora tenho que medir o tempo gasto com a ordenação.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode calcular o tempo de execução de funções utilizando C++11 com alta precisão utilizando a biblioteca [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono#std::chrono_library). Por ex:

```
auto inicio = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
...SEU CÓDIGO AQUI...
auto resultado = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - inicio;
long long microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(resultado).count();
```

Sendo que você pode substituir `std::chrono::microseconds` (microsegundos) por `std::chrono::milliseconds` (milissegundos), `std::chrono::seconds` (segundos) ou até mesmo `std::chrono::nanoseconds` (nanosegundos).

Answer (score 2):

Voce está usando linux como SO? Para um programa simples como esse eu sugiro que use `time ./a.out` no terminal, onde `a.out` é o executavel do seu programa. Esse comando imprime 3 linhas (explicadas bem resumidamente):

- `real`: Tempo real do comeco ao fim da execucao;
- `sys`: Tempo gasto pelo kernel do sistema no processo de execucao do seu programa;
- `user`: Tempo usado no *user-mode*. É o tempo que seu computador gasta no processo fora do kernel;

Comment: To usando o Windows